Asset library struggles with high poly meshes
I have problems with adding objects/collections into Blender Asset Library:
High Poly Objects: When you have a collection of multiple high-poly objects (in my case 2-4 objects with a total of over 1 million faces), applying "Mark as Asset" to the collection causes Blender to become unresponsive. However, if you join these objects into a single object, the "Mark as Asset" function works without issues.
Geometry Nodes Modifier: If you apply a Geometry Nodes modifier to an object that creates a large number of instances, Blender also struggles to add this object to the asset library. The solution is to apply "Realize instances" node, but what does it happens at all, why should I apply the node?

It's either a bug or a limitation. If you think it's a bug, you should report it. Either way, I don't really see what can be done about it in a Blender Stack Exchange answer. You should at least provide more detail about the assets, share a .blend file or describe exact steps to reproduce the issue if you wanted someone to take a closer look into it and have a possibility to come up with a workaround or solution.

Blender generates previews when you mark something as asset. The fact that it takes longer for high poly or high instance objects seems expected. Realize instances increases poly count and memory consumption, and destroys any operations that require instances.
